# NullPointerException retrieving saved picture on the sd-card

Tags: java, android, io, nullpointerexception

I am experiencing some problems when I try to retrieve a saved picture on the sd-card.

Basically, the code that I am using when an image is taken is:

```
    if(now==null){

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
            now = sdf.format(new Date());
        }

        myDirVids=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TimelapseVideos");
        if(!myDirVids.exists()){
            myDirVids.mkdirs();
        }
        myDirPhotos=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/TimelapsePhotos");
        if(!myDirPhotos.exists()){
            myDirPhotos.mkdirs();
        }

        myDir=new File(myDirPhotos+"/timelapse"+now);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00000");
        imagename = "Image-"+ decimalFormat.format(num) +".jpg";
        file = new File (myDir, imagename);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Just after this lines, I try to retrieve the image saved and I am getting a NullPointerException because it seems that is not available:

```
    Log.d(TAG, file.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d(TAG, imagename);

try { 
Thread.sleep(800); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {              
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the nullPointerException on the first line, `Log.d(TAG, file.getAbsolutePath());`

But if I put this line AFTER the sleep, no nullPointerException is thrown.
The sleep has to be superior to 500ms to not getting any error.

I don't know where the problem comes from, but I believe that when the FileOutPutStream operation finishes the smartphone is still saving the data in the sd-card. If I let the phone some time (0.5-1s) the problem disappear because the writing process has finalized.

My question is:

There is any way to know when a writing operation finishes?

Comment: `Just before this lines` -- do you mean `Just AFTER these lines` ?

Comment: @PeterK. Sorry, I mean AFTER.

Comment: What is the type and value of the `file` variable in your code above?

Comment: @unluddite
file = new File (myDir, imagename); Where myDir is a String of the path where I want to save the image and imagename is the name of the image like "image-00001.jpg"

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code for writing out the file? The FileOutputStream class doesn't have a `write()` method that takes a `byte[]` as an argument. Can you also include the code you use to try to read the file? Which line of code is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: @unluddite, No that's no the code that I am using, I just wanted to put the whole idea in a few lines.

That's some code: `

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00000");
   imagename = "Image-"+ decimalFormat.format(num) +".jpg";
   file = new File (myDir, imagename);
   if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
   try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    fos.write(data);
    fos.close();`

Comment: If you can just edit your original question to include the actual code and also point to the line that is causing the exception, that would be quite helpful.

Comment: @unluddite , I have modified my question, I believe that now is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the file exists, you can do-

```
File file = new File(getExternalCacheDirectory(), YOUR_FILE_NAME);
if (file.exists()) {
  // Exists
} else {
  // Doesn't exist
}
```

Also, you can use [MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to scan a file.

Comment: I am using a folder in to save the images on the sd-card, not a cache one. I define file as: new File(myDir,imagename). If I try file.exists() then NullPointerException is thrown. If I wait aprox 1second after I do fos.write(data), then no nullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: @MatiesPons Can't use something like if(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).exists()){}

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally fix my problem.

As I said, I was getting a NullPointerException when I was trying to access to the just saved image.
After saving it (and during 500ms) the "file" variable is null (for some reason that I do not know).

So I just added this line in order to know when the file is not null:

```
while(file==null){}

//retrieve file
```

Thank you for your time.